# Narrow search between two inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, for-loop, filter

I have two inputs fields, one text, the other select, I want to narrow the search based on each input. If both input fields have data they narrow down the search result. Otherwise they search the original array.

```
let dataArray = [{name: 'DataOne', place: 'italy'}, {name: 'Second data', place: 'berlin'}, {name: 'third data', place: 'barcelona'} ]

let searchStringName = ''
let searchSelectCity = ''
```

Comment: so where is your component?

Comment: I can write a component, but I thought maybe a function that could receive the data and strings from the input fields and then performs the logic

Comment: yes, the solution below is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you expecting something like this?

```js
var dataArray = [{name: 'DataOne', place: 'italy'}, {name: 'Second data', place: 'berlin'}, {name: 'third data', place: 'barcelona'} ]

var name = 'data'
var city = 'berlin'
function search(){
if(name&&city){
 return dataArray.filter((a)=>(a.name).includes(name)&&(a.place).includes(city))
}
else if(name){
  return dataArray.filter((a)=>(a.name).includes(name))
}
else if(city){
  return dataArray.filter((a)=>(a.place).includes(city))
}
else 
return dataArray
}
console.log(search())
```